# Initializing enum variables in a comparison function

Tags: java, enums

I am having trouble comparing an Enum value to a predefined value within a function.
 
I have an Enum setup as

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    A, B, C
}
```

Then in another class, I have a method which compares a `String` to the Enum values, and **returns the Enum value** if they are `equals` according to the `toString()` method of the Enum value.

**The Method**:

```
 /**
 * Example
 * @param someString - A string which could be equivalent to an SomeEnum value.
 * @return SomeEnum Type
 */
private static ClassA someMethod(String someString) {
    SomeEnum letterType; // Problem
    for (SomeEnum letter : SomeEnum.values()) {
        if (someString.equals(letter.toString())) {
            letterType = letter;
        }
    }
    return letterType;
}
```

The above code gives me an error stating that:

> the variable letterType may have not been initialized

*Fair enough, just instantiate it!...*

```
SomeEnum letterType = new SomeEnum(); // NO
```

**However** Enums (by definition) cannot be instantiated.
This leaves me with 2 options:

1. Initialize `letterType` on first use (within the `if`)
2. Initialize `letterType` by assigning it `null`

   ```
   /*Options*/
   //1. 
   if (someString.equals(letter.toString())){
       SomeEnum letterType = letter;
   }
   //2. 
   private static ClassA someMethod(String someString) {
       SomeEnum letterType = null;
       //...
   }
   ```

---

**Option 1** restricts me returning `letterType` as it is now not reachable. 
**Option 2** works, however instantiating with `null` seems like it is **not** good practice - correct me if I am wrong.

Besides using a `switch` statement and changing the function, it seems I am only able to achieve this using Option 2.

Is there another way to achieve this?/missing something simple..? 
Is my understanding of this concept incorrect...? 
Should I just be using a `switch` statement instead?

Comment: Return right away and throw an exception if not found. Returning a default value is then the only other option, whether it's `null` or something else.

Comment: You have to decide what you want your code to do if the `String` doesn't match any of the constants.  Throw?  Return null?  We can't tell you, there's no universal rule.  This is a decision you have to make.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with initialization or instantiation; those are just syntactical technicalities. The real question is what you want to do in the default case, i.e. where there is no match. Once you've solved that problem, there are a number of ways to formulate your code. On a related note, your method is awfully similar to `SomeEnum.valueOf(String)`.